# Saving all Windows 10 cmd window content

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, console

I have a fairly lengthy batch process that runs a number of other batch files and programs.  Some of the programs log to the window, but have already hooked the console streams so simple output redirection does not work. A lot of files are created during processing, but one file I cannot capture is the **overall console log** for the process.  The only way I see to do this is the cmd Window Title bar menu shown in the image below.  I know I could use some type of windows automation tool, but before resorting to that, I want to ask all of you if there is a way to automate the Cmd windows Title menu operations that is intrinsic to the Windows environment.

[image]

Comment: OK, that Title menu automation idea is a kludge.  Is there is a rational way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a short article with examples here:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-access-the-system-clipboard-copy-paste-from-the-command-line-c8615d510ae2

Using Windows intrinsic clip command to get the output, and using powershell get-clipboard to save that in a file.

```
>call _thFullMonty.cmd | clip
>PowerShell get-clipboard > _theFullMonty.log
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach runs into permissions problems accessing the clipboard more often than not.